# Mongo DB , how select all documents in match query?

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregate, document

FOR getting all documents, what I write instead of XXXX.
I want to get all values without a criterion. I must use aggregate and match function.
payload.sla.customer.externalId variable is string.

```html
db.collection.aggregate ( [
    { "$match" :    {        
    "payload.sla.customer.externalId" : XXXX 
    }}  
    ])
```

**collection sample example**

```html
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b929a84aff3dc185627add1"),
"payload" : { 
    "sla" : { 
            "customer" : { 
            "externalId" : "140689900", 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `all` equal to `all`? What does `payload.sla.customer.externalId` contain?

Comment: all = all , it is test. ı updated question.  payload.sla.customer.externalId  contains string.  ı want get all document with match function

Comment: If you want to return all the documents then you don't need to use `$match` stage. Run the query without any stage. Not sure why you want to do this.

Comment: I'll take the outside parameter, if there is no parameter, ı need to get all documents. so it is necessary

Comment: Then put the if else condition outside the query.

Comment: yeap, you know , how can ı get all document in match query

Comment: Still unclear to me what you are asking.